# sliding a tangent line along a curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, dynamic

I am confused by `Dynamic`. I am trying to slide a tangent line along a curve, without using `DynamicModule`, so that I can include it in a cdf. I have the sliding point working in the below, but the tangent line is static. How do I get the line moving as well?

```
LocatorPane[
 Dynamic[pt],
 plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
   Epilog -> {
     PointSize[Large],
     Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Sin[First[pt]]}]]
     }];
 TangentAngle = Cos[First[pt]];
 x1 = First[pt] - 0.5*Cos[TangentAngle];
 y1 = pt[[2]] - 0.5*Sin[TangentAngle];
 x2 = First[pt] + Cos[TangentAngle];
 y2 = pt[[2]] + Sin[TangentAngle];

 plot2 = Graphics[Line[{Dynamic[{x1, y1}], Dynamic[{x2, y2}]}]];
 Show[{plot1, plot2}], Appearance -> None
 ]
```

Comment: The answers to this question should be quite helpful : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-to-make-a-line-with-no-end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = {#[[1]], Sin[#[[1]]]}) &],
Dynamic@Plot[{Sin[x],
ConditionalExpression[Cos[pt[[1]]]*(x - pt[[1]]) + Sin[pt[[1]]],
 pt[[1]] - 1 <= x <= pt[[1]] + 1]}, {x, 0, 10},
PlotRange -> {{-2, 11}, {-2, 2}},
Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}],
Appearance -> None]
```

[image]

For arbitrary function `func`, replace `Cos` with `Derivative[1][func]`  in the first argument of `ConditionalExpression`.

Instead of `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}],` one can also use

```
Mesh -> {{pt[[1]]}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

**Update:** Using `Locator` as a graphics primitive, one can get the same result without having to use `LocatorPane`:

```
Dynamic@Plot[{Sin[x],
ConditionalExpression[Cos[pt[[1]]]*(x - pt[[1]]) + Sin[pt[[1]]],
pt[[1]] - 1 <= x <= pt[[1]] + 1]}, {x, 0, 10},
PlotRange -> {{-2, 11}, {-2, 2}},
Epilog ->  Dynamic@{Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = {#[[1]], Sin[#[[1]]]}) &],
  Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]]}]
```

Comment: very elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `Derivative` as well as your other suggestions. The last option using `Dynamic@Plot` works in a notebook but unfortunately does not work in a CDF.

Comment: You need to use  the piece `Dynamic@Plot..` as the first argument in `Manipulate[..., {dummycontrol, None}]` for it to work in a CDF. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to _MathematicaSE_.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this is already answered... here a short, straightforward, "solution", which might be instructive to people, not so deeply concerned with all that "Dynamic" stuff ;-)

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

tangent[f_, x0_, x_] := f'[x0] (x - x0) + f[x0]

   Manipulate[Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, p, x]}, {x, 0, 2 π},PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-3, 3}},
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point@{p, Sin[p]}}], {p, 0,  2 π}]
```

[image: Manipulate]

---

**(edit by J. M.)**

This is a variation of mgamer's proposal; I did not feel it deserved its own answer, but it was too long for a comment. This one eliminates the slider, and uses a `Locator` instead, so that one can slide the tangent line along the curve:

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-3, 3}}, 
                Epilog -> {{Directive[ColorData[97, 2], AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
                            InfiniteLine[{p[[1]], f[p[[1]]]}, {1, f'[p[[1]]]}]},
                           {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
                            Point[{p[[1]], f[p[[1]]]}]}}],
           {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
           Initialization :> (f[x_] := Sin[x])]
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could make your code work was to introduce a helper function. I have no experience with CDFs, but I would hope they allow such functions.

```
tangent[pt_] := Module[{tanAngle, xy1, xy2},
  tanAngle = ArcTan@Cos[pt[[1]]];
  xy1 = pt - 0.5 {Cos[tanAngle], Sin[tanAngle]};
  xy2 = pt + 0.5 {Cos[tanAngle], Sin[tanAngle]};
  Graphics[{Line[{xy1, xy2}]}]]

LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pt, (pt = With[{ptx = #[[1]]}, {ptx, Sin@ptx}]) &], 
  plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Dynamic@Point[pt]}];
  Dynamic@Show[{plot, tangent[pt]}], Appearance -> None]
```

[image: tangent demo]

Note the introduction of `ArcTan` in the calculation of the tangent angle and the use of the second argument of `Dynamic` in the locator pane.

Note: the second argument of `Dynamic` provides a way to constrain the movement of the locator. I use it to confine the locator to the curve.

Answer (score 1):

@m_goldberg: thanks for spotting the 'ArcTan'. Sine was not the best function to do this on. Unfortunately, i did not get your solution to work in a CDF.

However, with your suggestion and reading through the link from @Artes, my messy code has morphed into something that works:

```
LocatorPane[
Dynamic[pt],
 plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 11}, {-2, 2}},
  Epilog -> {
 PointSize[Large],
 Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Sin[First[pt]]}]],
 Line[Dynamic[{
    {First[pt] - Cos[ArcTan[Cos[First[pt]]]],
     Sin[First[pt]] - Sin[ArcTan[Cos[First[pt]]]]
     },
    {First[pt] + Cos[ArcTan[Cos[First[pt]]]],
     Sin[First[pt]] + Sin[ArcTan[Cos[First[pt]]]]
     }
    }]]}
 ], Appearance -> None]
```

[image: output]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I first thought to make this a comment, but I wanted to give an example for the OP to test:  `DynamicModule` is supported by CDF Player, or at least the code below works on both the v8 and v9 CDF Player.  (It's a little more elaborate than what the OP proposed, but I wanted to test a few things and decided to leave them in.)

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1.5, f = Sin, tangetLine, x1 = 0, x2 = 10}, 
 tangetLine[x_, a0_] := f[a0] + f'[a0] (x - a0);
 Labeled[LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{a, f[a]}, (a = Clip[#[[1]], {x1, x2}]) &],
   Dynamic@Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}, PlotRange -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> {1, 0.2},
     Epilog -> {Line[{#, tangetLine[#, a]} & /@
                 {a - 1/Sqrt[1 + f'[a]^2], a + 1/Sqrt[1 + f'[a]^2]}]}, 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic],
   Appearance -> Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]],
  SetterBar[
   Dynamic[f], # -> TraditionalForm[#[x]] & /@
    {Sin, Cos, # ((#/π)^2 - 1) (#/(2 π) - 1) (#/(3 π) - 1) (#/(4 π) - 1) &},
   Alignment -> Center],
  Top]
]
```

[image: output]

Notes:

1. A tangent line one unit long in each direction seems to be desired.  But if the scales on the axes aren't the same, then the tangent line will appear to change length.  So I include `AspectRatio -> Automatic` just in case. (`Cos[ArcTan[f'[a]]]` simplifies to `1/Sqrt[1+f'[a]^2]`.)
2. I clipped the `Locator` position to the domain `{x1, x2}` to constrain it to the domain passed to `Plot`.
3. The option `Alignment` turns red in `SetterBar`, but it seems to get passed to the component `Setter`s without generating errors.  (To get rid of the `SetterBar`, copy the `LocatorPane[..]` code and paste it over the `Labeled[..]` code
4. There is also [this Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SecantAndTangentLines/) that moves tangents, as well as secants, whose code could be adapted.  CDFs support `Manipulate`, too.