# Manipulate flickering and consuming lots of CPU

Tags: manipulate

I am new to *Mathematica* and was experimenting with a simply problem of plotting a tangent to a curve and being able to move the point at which the tangent is drawn using `Manipulate`. When I run the following, the cell flickers a lot and it also seems to consume a lot of CPU? Is there a way to avoid this?

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{f, x, y, dx, dy},
    dx = dy = 1;
    f[x_] := x^2;
    tangent[x_, y_] := {{x - dx, y - f'[x] dy}, {x + dx, y + f'[x] dy}};
    g = Graphics[Line @ tangent[x0, f[x0]], PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
    p = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}];
    Show[p, g]],
  {{x0, 2}, -4, 4}]
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve)

Comment: Thanks but doesn't explain why the above doesn't work ? In my example it should just evaluate the function f[x] & tangent[] when i move the slider but clearly its doing something different.

Comment: The link shows one correct approach to doing what you want and answers your question "how to avoid this?" If your question is really: how do I debug this? -- well, this isn't a debugging service. I will say this -- defining a `Module` inside a `Manipulate` is not a good idea, nor is evaluating the derivative of a simple function over and over.

Comment: Thanks. But why is evaluating a function inside a manipulate a bad idea ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with evaluating a function in a `Manipulate`, but taking the derivative of `x^2` many times when it could done once is not good.

Comment: Every time you change the value of a variable, e.g., `p` or `g`, *Mathematica* will update the Manipulate (i.e., reevaluate it).  You can avoid it by rewriting the code, using `TrackedSymbols :> {x}`, or localizing `p`, `g`, `tangent` inside the Module.

Comment: I noticed that you did not accept any answers (of the 11 questions you have asked on this site). I consider this impolite (more info here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 7):

I hope you'll forgive my changing one thing that's been bugging me about the code:
If $y=f(x)$, then $dy = f'(x)\; dx$, not $f'(x)\; dy$.  (The original code works because `dy` is set equal to `dx`.)

```
tangent[x_, dx_, f_] := {{x - dx, f[x] - f'[x] dx}, {x + dx, f[x] + f'[x] dx}};
f[x_] := x^2;
Manipulate[With[{dx = 1},
  p = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, Epilog -> Dynamic@Line@tangent[x0, dx, f]]],
 {{x0, 2}, -4, 4}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I also wrapped the tangent line in `Dynamic`.  The tangent line is the only thing that changes, and adding `Dynamic` makes it the only thing recalculated when `x0` changes.  The plot of `f[x]` is not recalculated, which lowers CPU usage even more.  That savings is unimportant in this example, but the principle illustrated is useful.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware of Dynamic so useful. Thanks for spotting the typo in dy.

Answer (score 5):

Well, while your (David McHarg's) current solution is much better, sometimes one can not avoid some heavy recalculation inside `Manipulate`. For such cases `TrackedSymbols` is indispensable. This tells manipulate which symbols to monitor for change. So this works as expected:

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{f, x, y, dx, dy}, dx = dy = 1;
  f[x_] := x^2;
  tangent[x_, y_] := {{x - dx, y - f'[x] dy}, {x + dx, y + f'[x] dy}};
  g = Graphics[Line@tangent[x0, f[x0]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
  p = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}];
  Show[p, g]], {{x0, 2}, -4, 4}, TrackedSymbols :> {x0}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i was looking for. Always good to understand different approaches.

Answer (score 5):

`TrackedSymbols` is not needed if one just localizes all variables in Modules (which is what one should do in the first place). Many like to use global variables all over the place and this causes such problems.

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{x, y, dx, dy, g, p},

  dx = dy = 1;
  g = Graphics[Line@tangent[x, x0, dx, dy, f],PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
  p = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}];
  Show[p, g]
 ],

 {{x0, 2}, -4, 4},

 Initialization :>
  {
   tangent[var_Symbol, x0_, dx_, dy_, f_]:= Module[{der = D[f, var] /. var -> x0},
     {{x0 - dx, f[x0] - der dy}, {x0 + dx, f[x0] + der dy}}
   ];

   f[x_] := x^2;
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem by changing things around a little. This resolves the flickering and CPU usage.

```
Module[{f,x,y,dx,dy},
dx=dy=1;
f[x_]:=x^2;
tangent[x_,y_]:={{x-dx,y-f'[x] dy},{x+dx,y+f'[x] dy}};
p=Plot[f[x],{x,-5,5}];
tangent[x_]:=Graphics[Line@tangent[x,f[x]],PlotRange->{{-5,5},{-5,5}}];
Manipulate[Show[p,tangent[x0]],{{x0,2},-4,4}]
]
```

Regards
David.