# Manipulate keeps replaying the animation non-stop

Tags: manipulate

I made a notebook with the following code, but for some reason when I evaluate it it keeps replaying repeatedly.  What is causing this?

Thanks.

```
RandomWalk[n_, roi_, bi_, 
  rake_] := (pwin = bi (1 + roi)/(2 (bi - rake)); 
  NestWhileList[# + 
     RandomChoice[{pwin, 1 - pwin} -> {1 - 2 rake/bi, -1}] &, 
   0, True &, 0, n])

Manipulate[(data = RandomWalk[nrTournaments, roi, bi, rake]; 
  dollarWon = biWon bi; biWon = Last[data]; 
  ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]), {{nrTournaments, 10000, 
   "tournaments"}, 0, 100000, 100}, {{roi, 0.015, "ROI"}, 0, 20, 
  0.001}, {{bi, 60, "BI ($)"}, 0, 10000, 
      1}, {{rake, 1.26, "rake ($)"}, 0, 500, 0.01}, 
     Panel[Grid[{{Dynamic[
          Row[{"BI won: ", ToString[biWon], " (", 
            Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
         If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], ")"}]]}}, 
   Alignment -> Left]], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: This [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/manipulate-flickering-and-consuming-lots-of-cpu) gives several approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that by default, whenever a symbol in the `Manipulate` change value, the `Manipulate` expression is reevaluated.  This means that when `data`, `dollarWon` etc. are changed in a given evaluation, their changes trigger another reevaluation and you get an infinite loop.

The way around this is to control the tracked symbols with the `TrackedSymbols` option.

```
Manipulate[data = RandomWalk[nrTournaments, roi, bi, rake];
 dollarWon = biWon bi; biWon = Last[data];
 Dynamic@ListPlot[data, Joined -> True],

 {{nrTournaments, 10000, "tournaments"}, 0, 100000, 100},
 {{roi, 0.015, "ROI"}, 0, 20, 0.001},
 {{bi, 60, "BI ($)"}, 0, 10000, 1},
     {{rake, 1.26, "rake ($)"}, 0, 500, 0.01},

 Panel[Grid[{{Dynamic[
      Row[{"BI won: ", ToString[biWon], " (", 
        Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
         If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], ")"}]]}}, 
   Alignment -> Left]],
 SaveDefinitions -> True, TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

Setting the option to `True` means only the control variables are tracked.  It is equivalent in this case to the setting `TrackedSymbols :> {nrTournaments, roi, bi, rake}`.

With only the `TrackedSymbols` option, the `Manipulate` is initially evaluated twice, and once there after for every change of inputs.  To fix this, put the `ListPlot` inside a `Dynamic`.

---

To run more trials on the same input, one way is to track a dummy variable. (I haven't discovered a better way.  `Update` does not seem applicable.  I can't figure out how to force updating without an actual change.)

```
trial = 0;
Manipulate[trial;
 data = RandomWalk[nrTournaments, roi, bi, rake];
 dollarWon = biWon bi; biWon = Last[data];
 Dynamic@ListPlot[data, Joined -> True],
 {{nrTournaments, 10000, "tournaments"}, 0, 100000, 100},
 {{roi, 0.015, "ROI"}, 0, 20, 0.001},
 {{bi, 60, "BI ($)"}, 0, 10000, 1},
     {{rake, 1.26, "rake ($)"}, 0, 500, 0.01},
     Panel[Grid[{{Dynamic[
          Row[{"BI won: ", ToString[biWon], " (", 
            Style["$" <> ToString[dollarWon], 
         If[dollarWon >= 0, Darker[Green], Red]], ")"}]]}}, 
   Alignment -> Left]],
 Button["Run again", trial++],
 SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {nrTournaments, roi, bi, rake, trial}]
```

You can also make `trial` a `Manipulate` variable with a slider.  Add the following to the variable declarations:

```
{trial, 1, 10^6, 1}
```

If `trial` at the beginning of the `Manipulate` expression is replaced by `SeedRandom[trial]`. then trials with the same inputs will be reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would like to add a button to recalculate without changing the inputs. I tried to add a button like this: Button["Run again", (nrTournaments = nrTournaments + 1; 
  nrTournaments = nrTournaments - 1)] but it doesn't work very well.  What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful.  I was looking at ControlType -> None as a way to add a dummy control but it didn't work.

Comment: @dabd You could try something like `{{trial, 0}, Button["Run again", trial++] &}` as the variable declaration.  `ControlType -> None` adds the variable without a control; you would still need a way to change its value to trigger an update.  The variable will be localized in the `DynamicModule` that the `Manipulate` creates.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you told it to simulate 10000 times at initialization. Change this to something more reasonable (like 10) and it will only do 10.

Comment: My intention is for it to generate a list with nrTournaments elements and then to plot the result. It looks like it is generating nrTournaments lists and plotting each one instead.  How can I change it to do what I want?