# Why does my Dynamic NonliearModelFit keep running?

Tags: dynamic, fitting

I have complex data and which I am fitting to a complex formula. In order to use `NonlinearModelFit` I split the formula and the data into real and imaginary parts.

As usual `NonlinearModelFit` is  sensitive to initial conditions so I have a `DynamicModule` to help me find these. My problem is that when inside a `DynamicModule` `NonlinearModelFit` keeps running and never stops.

I have made a reduced version of the `DynamicModule` below to show the effect. The local variable numbers never stop increasing.

Why is this? I feel it should just do one operation and stop.

The data is:

```
data = {{267.761, 0.666697 - 0.117395 I}, {267.794, 0.720659 - 0.140544 I}, 
        {267.827, 0.78293 - 0.165958 I}, {267.861, 0.850505 - 0.19637 I},
        {267.894, 0.933982 - 0.239532 I}, {267.927, 1.04094 - 0.303451 I},
        {267.96, 1.15656 - 0.382384 I}, {267.994, 1.30706 - 0.505816 I}, 
        {268.027, 1.48614 - 0.684103 I}, {268.06, 1.69699 - 0.969217 I}, 
        {268.094, 1.89745 - 1.43193 I}, {268.127,1.9794 - 2.19671 I}, 
        {268.16, 1.49939 - 3.27732 I}, {268.193, 0.0979582 - 4.0018 I}, 
        {268.227, -1.38062 - 3.44199 I}, {268.26, -1.96791 - 2.37086 I}, 
        {268.293, -1.95989 - 1.55105 I}, {268.327, -1.77203 - 1.04211 I},
        {268.36, -1.572 - 0.722879 I}, {268.393, -1.37354 - 0.5245 I}, 
        {268.427, -1.21688 - 0.402393 I}, {268.46, -1.08912 - 0.310994 I},
        {268.493, -0.983056 - 0.249877 I}, {268.526, -0.897219 - 0.205772 I}, 
        {268.56, -0.823682 - 0.173521 I}, {268.593, -0.758923 - 0.150585 I}, 
        {268.626, -0.7049 - 0.127326 I}};
```

The fitting module is

```
ClearAll[nlmFit];
nlmFit::usage =  "nlmFit[data,{fnest,\[Zeta]est}] uses nonlinear model fit to get \
                values for constant (h0r,h0i), residue (gr,gi), natural frequency \
                (fn) and damping ratio (\[Zeta]). All data is fitted. Output is the \
                standard NonLinearModelFit";

 nlmFit[data0_, {fnest_, \[Zeta]est_}] := Module[
      {nn, ff, hh, data, model, y, f, hr, hi, rr, ri, fn, \[Zeta]}
  ,
  ff = data0[[All, 1]];
  hh = data0[[All, 2]];
  nn = Length[ff];
  data = Join[
              Transpose[{ff, ConstantArray[0, nn], Re[hh]}],
              Transpose[{ff, ConstantArray[1, nn], Im[hh]}]
             ];

 model = (1 - y) (( f^2 hr + f (rr - 2 fn hr Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]) + 
   fn (fn hr - ri \[Zeta] - rr Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]))/( f^2 + fn^2 - 2 f fn Sqrt[1 -
   \[Zeta]^2])) + y ((f^2 hi + f (ri - 2 fn hi Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]) +  fn (fn hi + 
   rr \[Zeta] - ri Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]))/(f^2 + fn^2 - 2 f fn Sqrt[1 - \[Zeta]^2]));

 NonlinearModelFit[data, 
                   model, 
                   {{fn, fnest}, {\[Zeta], \[Zeta]est}, rr, ri, hr, hi}, 
                   {f, y}]

 ]
```

The `DynamicModule` is

```
ClearAll[dfit];

dfit[data_, {fn_, \[Zeta]e_}] := DynamicModule[{fitdata},

 Dynamic[fitdata = nlmFit[data, {fn, \[Zeta]e}];

 fitdata["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]]
 ]
```

To run the `DynamicModule`

```
dfit[data, {268, 0.0003}]
```

...and the output never stops changing.
Why is the code running again and again? Thanks

Comment: Your example boils down to: `DynamicModule[{a},
 Dynamic[a = RandomReal[]; a]
 ]`. I'd move assignment outside `Dynamic`.

Comment: @Kuba If I understand the Q, the OP cannot move the assignment outside.  Initial conditions are manually set inside `Dynamic` but that code has been removed.  Based on my understanding, what the OP needs is `TrackedSymbols` (and possibly `Refresh`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I suppose it is the problem with the scheme. If those `fn` and `ZetaE` are changed with `Slider` or something, then there is not need to keep the assignment inside the same `Dynamic` as the table is. And if it is some kind of automatic loop, `Dynamic` itself is not really the solution and still I imagine it can be split. However, I do often miss the point of the question ;P

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that's possible. The OP says it's a stripped down example, and it's hard to know how faithfully it represents the problem.  But the explicit question, which has been answered on the site before, can be answered: An update is triggered every time because `fitdata` is assigned a new value inside `Dynamic` and it is a tracked symbol.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's more tricky, your description fits: `DynamicModule[{a},
 Dynamic[a = RandomReal[]]
 ]` but the behaviour is different. Moreover, without DM it is smarter too: `Dynamic[a = RandomReal[]; a]`.

Comment: Dear @Kuba and MichaelE2 thanks for picking this up after so long. Is there anything I can do to help?

Comment: @Kuba I believe that is because (1) `Random*` function "are not ticklish," and (2) a mystery reason. :) My guess about the difference when `a` is a front-end DynamicModule variable and when `a` is a kernel variable is complicated, but has to do with which "owns" the variable.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I must say all I I know about that is what you stated in your comment. But it is not the best answer, isn't it? :) Hugh, can you say how those initial values are provided to Dynamic?

Comment: @Kuba By "mystery reason" and "guess" I mean I do not know the best answer. (I assume you mean the answer to why your `RandomReal` examples behave the way they do).

Comment: @MichaelE2 The initial values are almost certainly given by sliders. I am trying to dig out the original problem. I have the post but that is in a separate folder from the original problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I did and I don't know either :(.

Comment: These might be considered duplicates, but this issue can be complicated by the particulars in each situation: [18978](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18979), [24212](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24212), [33990](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33990), [56750](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56750). Related: [29678](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29678), [49257](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49285).

Comment: @Hugh You might look at the links in my previous comment just above this one.  The solution to your Q is `Dynamic[<code>, TrackedSymbols :> {}]` or `Dynamic[<code>, TrackedSymbols :> {x, y,...}]` where `x`, `y`,... are your slider variables, but **not** `fitdata`.  The reason is explained (imo) in some answers to the linked questions.

Comment: @Hugh You could (and should) post the solution as an answer.  (We actually encourage it.)

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question after a suggestion by MichaelE2

Here is a second version of dfit (dfit4) which has Sliders and TrackedSymbols. The sliders are a method of finding appropriate initial conditions. The solution to the problem is to include TrackedSymbols in the Dynamic that calculates the NonLinearModelFit.

```
 ClearAll[dfit4];
  dfit4[data_] := DynamicModule[{fitdata, fn = 268, \[Zeta]e = 0.0001},
   Column[{
   Row[{"Estimate frequency ", Slider[Dynamic[fn], {0, 400}], 
   Dynamic[fn]}],
   Row[{"Damping ratio ", Slider[Dynamic[\[Zeta]e], {0, 0.001}], 
   Dynamic[\[Zeta]e]}],
    Dynamic[
     fitdata = nlmFit[data, {fn, \[Zeta]e}];
     fitdata["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"],
     TrackedSymbols :> {fn, \[Zeta]e}]
   }]
   ]
```

Thanks to MichaelE2