# Updating Manipulate output from within a Button

Tags: manipulate, button

Consider this (**edit**: `Pause[3]` represents some long computation the button should do):

```
Manipulate[Dynamic@output, Button["do", 
    output = "Paused..."; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[3]; output = "done"]]
```

This *works* in that we see the Paused message briefly. But it uses a global variable `output`.

1) If you take out the `FinishDynamic[]`, or the first `Dynamic@` it does not work.

2) If you add a `{output,ControlType->None}` to the `Manipulate`, it does not work.

3) Similarly for wrapping it all within a `DynamicModule[{output},]`

Is there a better way to update the output of a `Manipulate` from within a `Button`? I'd like to avoid eg `Refresh` every second since the recalculation will in principle happen very rarely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that anything is wrong with Michaels answer but I wanted to mention that the following does what I think you expect in a somewhat more straightforward way:

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic[output, TrackedSymbols :> {output}],
  Button["do", output = "Paused..."; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[3]; 
   output = "done",
   Method -> "Queued"
 ],
 {output, ControlType -> None}
]
```

the trick is to add the `TrackedSymbols` option to `Dynamic`. I did additionally add the `Method->"Queued"` option to the button, which is not necessary for this example to run but certainly is a good idea once your calculation (or `Pause`) takes or could take more than 6 second (or more precisely what `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` is set to).

I would also like to mention that I think once you start to build an interface where you want precise control about when which part of the code is evaluated it might actually become simpler/more straightforward to use the lower level "dynamic language" constructs directly instead of manipulating `Manipulate`, e.g.:

```
DynamicModule[{output = ""},
  Panel[
    Column[{
      Button["Do",
        output = "Paused...";
        Pause[3];
        output = "Done.";
        ,
        Method -> "Queued"
      ],
      Panel[Pane[Dynamic[output, TrackedSymbols :> {output}], {100, 50}]]
    }]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Both your and Michael's solutions are perfect. I particularly like how this one requires fewer edits to the example code, and the self-`TrackedSymbols` trick is an interesting one to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipMaymin: thanks for the accept. I would like to draw your attention to the `Method->"Queued"` setting, you almost certainly will find that necessary for your real problem...

Comment: Yes, I use that of course, thank you. Just left it out of the question for brevity, probably too much brevity. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after.  Here are two ideas.  The first one preserves the waiting 3 seconds. If that's not important, see further down.

```
Manipulate[output,
 {{output, "new", ""},
  DynamicModule[{timer = Infinity},
    Button[
     DynamicWrapper["do", 
      If[Clock[{0, Infinity}] >= timer + 3, output = "done"]],
     output = "Paused..."; timer = Clock[{0, Infinity}]]] &},
 TrackedSymbols :> {output}]
```

I used something like `{{update, 0}, Button["Update", update++] &}` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24212/manipulate-keeps-replaying-the-animation-non-stop/24219#24219).  If `trial` appears in the body of the `Manipulate`, even just as `update;`.  Here's an example:

```
Manipulate[update;
 RandomReal[],
 {{update, 0}, None},
 Button["Update", update++]
 ]
```

**Update** - Third example: I'm still not sure how `Pause[3]` and `output` are to be integrated into the `Manipulate`.  Here's another idea:

```
Manipulate[
 If[output === "Paused",
  output = (Pause[3]; "done")];
 Dynamic@output,
 {{output, "done"}, None},
 Button["do", output = "Paused"]]
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your first one. The `Pause` was just to represent some long computation. Where would I put the bulk of such code in your example?

Comment: Also, I like the `Button&` approach, but when I try `Manipulate[Dynamic@output, {{output, "start",}, 
Button["do", output = "Paused..."; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[3]; output = "done"] &}]` it never displays "Paused"

Comment: I don't know `DynamicWrapper` very well but it seems to essentially refresh every second? For example running `counter = 0; Button[DynamicWrapper["hi", counter++], Print@counter]` and pressing the button gives large numbers.

Comment: @PhilipMaymin I think the first solution above is not what you're after, if `Pause` represents any function. -- The `Button` (2nd comment) never displays "Paused" because the whole computation is completed before the Front End is notified of any updates. -- The `counter++` is executed every time `counter` changes value, similar to `Dynamic[counter++]`; and since it changes value every time `counter++` is executed, you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Your updated solution is perfect! Great solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: @PhilipMaymin You're welcome.