# Flickering GIF in exporting Animation

Tags: export, animation, gif-format

I am trying to export an Animate object to a GIF file, but the saved GIF file keeps flickering. How do I fix this?

```
X[t_, p_] = Table[{Sin[t + (k*\[Pi])/p]}, {k, 0, 8}];
Cr[t_, p_] = 
  FullSimplify[Integrate[X[s, p].Transpose[X[s, p]], {s, 0, t}]];
Eig2[t_, p_] := Eigenvectors[Cr[t, p]][[1]]
Export["cm.gif", 
 Animate[GraphicsGrid[{{MatrixPlot[Cr[2*\[Pi], u], 
      ImageSize -> {350, 350}], Plot[X[t, u], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
     ListPlot[Eig2[2 \[Pi], u]]}}], {u, 0.01, 1, 0.01}]]
```

produces:

[image]

which is *terrible!*

Comment: Try `Cr[t_, p_] := NIntegrate[X[s, p].Transpose[X[s, p]], {s, 0, t}];` instead.

Comment: I haven't looked at Henrik's solution, maybe this problem is already solved, but I just want to say that the flickering is definitely because the code fails for some values of `u`. You can see the red error rectangle for the frames that fail. The right question isn't why the animation flickers, but why the code fails for some `u`.

Comment: When I ran this code exactly as is the gif came out fine. This may be a problem with the dynamic updating. Here is a similar [problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/manipulate-flickering-and-consuming-lots-of-cpu) occurring with manipulate. When the program runs is your CPU or memory maxing out? If this is the case I think that as @Henrik pointed out there may be places to optimize your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
ClearAll[X, Cr, Eig2];
X[t_, p_] := Table[{Sin[t + (k Pi)/p]}, {k, 0, 8}];
Cr[t_, p_] := Cr[t, p] = 
   NIntegrate[X[s, p].Transpose[X[s, p]], {s, 0, t}] // Quiet;
Eig2[t_, p_] := Eigenvectors[Cr[t, p]][[1]];
```

Then try

```
Animate[GraphicsGrid[{{MatrixPlot[Cr[2 Pi, u], ImageSize -> {350, 350}],
  Plot[X[t, u], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], ListPlot[Eig2[2 Pi, u]]}}],
    {u, 0.01, 1, 0.01}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

a few times to see if you like the animation. Then wrap it in `Export[]`.