# Plot of differential equations?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

`y=C/(x+1)`  ( I get it from `sol=DSolve[y'[x]==-y[x]/(x+1),y[x],x]`)

How I can plot this `"sol"` with showing tangents in list of points?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[t, f]
f[c_][x_] := Evaluate[First[y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> c]];
t[c_][x_, a_] := f[c][a] + (x - a) (D[f[c][s], s] /. s -> a)
mesh = -1/2;

Show[Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[c][z], {c, {-2, -1, 1, 2}}]], {z, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLegends -> (HoldForm[f][#][x] & /@ {-2, -1, 1, 2}), ImageSize -> Large],
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[ConditionalExpression[t[c][z, mesh], -1/3 + mesh <= z <= 1/3 + mesh],
   {c, {-2, -1, 1, 2}}]], {z, -3, 3}, 
  Mesh -> {{mesh}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], PlotStyle -> Dashed,
  PlotLegends -> (HoldForm[f[#]'][a] & /@ {-2, -1, 1, 2})]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ye but i want that PLOT+ to plot of some tangets of that curves in some points ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић, please see the updated version.

Comment: Oh ye , that i wanted, tnx :)