# How to shorten the length of the tangent line

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I have all the equations down to manipulate the tangent line on the graph... but the tangent line is too long, what would be the best way to shorten it?

```
f[x_] = Sin[x];

Plot[f[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]

tangent[f_, a_, x_] := f'[a] (x - a) + f[a]

Manipulate[Plot[{f[x], tangent[f, p, x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point@{p, Sin[p]}}], {p, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Comment: Related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18090/3066

Answer (score 3):

This is a kludge onto your code.  I would have written the whole thing rather differently.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {f[x], If[Abs[p - x] < 1, 100 tangent[f, p, x], 0]},
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point@{p, Sin[p]}}],
 {p, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could replace the `0` by `Indeterminate` or `Undefined` in the `If[]` statement to eliminate the line along the x axis.  Is the factor of `100` a typo, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ConditionalExpression` as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18090/3066) linked by m_goldberg in comments:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], ConditionalExpression[tangent[f, p, x], p - .5 <= x <= p + .5]}, 
   {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.015], Point@{p, Sin[p]}}], {p, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

You can replace `ConditionalExpression[...]` with

```
Piecewise[{{tangent[f, p, x],  p - .5 <= x <= p + .5}}, Undefined]
```

to get the same result.