Any other better way to draw a dynamic tangent to a curve?
I want to draw a dynamic diagram of the tangent line at any point on the curve  y = =Log[x].

Clear["`*"]
f[x_] := Log[x]
tangentLine[x_] = Normal[Series[f[x], {x, x0, 1}]] // Simplify

tL = y == tangentLine[x]
tL1[x0_] = tangentLine[x]
sol = First@Solve[{tL /. Thread[{x, y} -> {0, 0}]}, x0]
tL /. sol
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], tL1[x0]}, {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-2, 5}}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[{x0, f[x0]}]}], {x0, 1, 7}]


Based on qwerty's Cmt.
Clear["`*"]
f[x_] := Log[x]
tangentLine[x_,x0_] = Normal[Series[f[x], {x, x0, 1}]] // Simplify
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x],tangentLine[x,x0]}, {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-2, 5}}, 
  Epilog -> {Point[{x0, f[x0]}]}], {x0, 1, 7}]


In particular, this answer is the same idea: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-to-make-a-line-with-no-end/10673#10673
